# Raspberry Pi based fingerprint authentication for a large database

Tags: raspberry-pi, fingerprint

I am building a student attendance system using a fingerprint sensor. However, all off-the-shelf fingerprint sensors only support a maximum of around 100 fingerprints on the device flash itself.

In some of the fingerprint sensors I have used, I am able to get the finegrprint "template" off the device (for ex in the: [R305](http://www.rhydolabz.com/documents/finger-print-module.pdf) and [GT-511C3](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11792))

Is there any way for me (open source) to match the minutiae "templates" from these sensors in the cloud or even on the pi itself.

Or even a way to upload previous matches into the fingerprint sensor flash dynamically (say, in sets of 60 fingerprints, as I would require only 60 per class)

I can provide code to read the sensor, but it is mostly based of [Adafruit Library](https://github.com/sparkfun/Fingerprint_Scanner-TTL) on github.

Here is the sample output in hex that someone online received from the sensor:

```
EF, 1, FF, FF, FF, FF, 2, 0, 82, 3, 1, 5F, 25, 0, 0, FE, 
3E, FC, 2, F8, 2, F0, 0, F0, 0, F0, 0, E0, 0, E0, 0, E0, 
0, E0, 0, E0, 0, E0, 0, E0, 0, E0, 0, E0, 0, E0, 0, E0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 64, 11, E4, FE, 6C, A0, A6, BE, 25, 23, 67, DE, 3C, AA, D1, 
3E, 71, AF, 67, 9E, 3B, 3F, E7, 9E, 3D, B, 50, 7F, 58, 34, 51, 
7F, 27, BB, A6, FF, 24, 41, D0, 5F, 59, 8, 63, 94, 5C, B, A5, 
9C, 33, 39, 67, BC, 73, 13, E4, 75, 74, 10, 4C, 7A, 2B, 1B, CF, 
32, 38, B1, D1, 3A, 36, BC, 11, 1A, 2F, BB, EF, 1, FF, FF, FF, 
FF, 2, 0, 82, 33, 8E, 27, 7B, 6C, C, 4E, 18, 35, 11, 10, 72, 
32, 12, E6, F2, 38, 1E, 8E, F8, 3C, 35, 51, 78, 28, 1E, 66, D3, 
33, A2, E6, 99, 40, 35, E7, F9, 6E, 8D, E2, F6, 2C, 34, D1, 70, 
34, 16, E6, 34, 3B, 96, CF, 8E, 40, 25, 26, B4, 32, 2F, A7, D4, 
36, 24, 8F, F2, 28, 36, 91, CD, 26, 2E, EB, 50, 26, 31, 14, B1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know only one open-source solution for this, it's the SDK provided by [NIST](http://www.nist.gov/) for fingerprint recognition: [NBIS](http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/nbis.cfm).

You could downloaded [here](http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/nigos.cfm).

Comment: @RohinGopalakrishnan Is it useful ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it, but there is some problem.
It is easy to save fingerprint template to a file or database in hex format.
Even you can match 2 templates.
But the problem is how to download templates from database or file back to R305.

Comment: Uploading & downloading from the R305 is possible, please check the [datasheet](http://www.rhydolabz.com/documents/finger-print-module.pdf) (_page 15 | UpChar_)